# how to filter json array by a value of a nested key - in python

Tags: python, arrays, json, filter

I am trying to filter a json with an array that can have several objects but can also be empty.

## **input:**

Where everything is fine, it is not empty and I have my customerKey inside the first level:

```
    "mainArray": [
        {
            "errorsArray": [],
            "errorCode": "0",
                        "customerKey": "UUID-1"
        },
        {
            "errorsArray": [],
            "errorCode": "0",
                        "customerKey": "UUID-2"
        }
    ]
```

but when there is an error I get my key inside a nested array of errors:

```
    "mainArray": [
        {
            "errorsArray": [
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "1"
                },
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "2"
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "1"
        },
        {
            "errorsArray": [],
            "errorCode": "0",
                        "customerKey": "UUID-2"
        }
    ]
```

## **output:**

I would like to filter my "mainField", leaving only customer with UUID-1.

expected output for when everything is ok:

```
    "mainArray": [
        {
            "errorsArray": [],
            "errorCode": "0",
                        "customerKey": "UUID-1"
        }
    ]
```

expected output for when there are errors:
but when there is an error I get my key inside a nested array of errors:

```
    "mainArray": [
        {
            "errorsArray": [
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "1"
                },
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "2"
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "1"
        }
    ]
```

## **additional info:**

I am mentioning that inside errorsArray I do not except to get different customerKeys.
I am also mentioning that changing this input is not an option at this moment.

Thank you :)

What I tried so far is:

the following technique obviously works only for situations where there are no errors:

```
filtered = [obj for obj in mainArray if (obj.get('customerKey',{}) == 'UUID-1')] if len(mainArray ) != 0 else [{}]
```

It does not work when there are errors because the customerKey is only inside the inner array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested list comprehension for this:

```
mainArray = [
        {
            "errorsArray": [
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "1"
                },
                {
                    "customerKey": "UUID-1",
                    "description": "error desc",
                    "errorCode": "2"
                }
            ],
            "errorCode": "1"
        },
        {
            "errorsArray": [],
            "errorCode": "0",
                        "customerKey": "UUID-2"
        }
    ]
    
filtered = [x for x in mainArray if [y for y in x["errorsArray"] if y["customerKey"] == "UUID-1"]]

print(filtered)
```

the if in 'x' comprehension checks whether the 'y' (errors) list is not empty. The 'y' list checks UUID.

Comment: Thanks! Simple and clever...  **emoji of someone that feels dumb..**